How must I find the third vertex of an equilateral / right isosceles triangle given the coordinates of 2 vertices?
This question has been asked in different ways at different points of time in the Math SE, but I'm trying to look for proof-wise simplicity here.
If the ends of hypotenuse of a right isosceles triangle are $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ then the coordinates of the third point are expected to be $$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2\pm(y_1-y_2)}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2\mp(x_1-x_2)}{2}\right)$$
In a similar fashion, if two vertices of a equilateral triangle are $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ then the third vertex is supposed to be:
$$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2\mp\sqrt3(y_2-y_1)}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2\pm\sqrt3(x_2-x_1)}{2}\right)$$
I tried to prove this with the help of simple distance formula and foot of perpendicular. Somewhat like this: in the isosceles right triangle case, if the unknown vertex is $(x,y)$, then
$$(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2=(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2$$
$$(x-x_1){^2}+(y-y_1){^2}=(y-y_2){^2}+(x-x_2){^2}$$
and then simplifying, but I then got stuck somewhere in between the expansions.
Could someone provide a simple proof on these lines? I am not looking for proofs based on rotating the axes or shifting the origin via specific angles, as I found plenty of those already.

Could you edit into your question what you tried "with the help of simple distance formula"?  The length of the side you have is $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ and it should not be difficult to show the new sides are $\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ or $1$ times that in the two cases

Yes, but we need the specific coordinates of that expression: $$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2\mp\sqrt3(y_2-y_1)}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2\pm\sqrt3(x_2-x_1)}{2}\right)$$ The sides are fine, I just need help on how to expand on that to get the concise format of the expression as given above.

If you use complex numbers with vertices $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ it is easy to see that the third vertex of an equilateral triangle must be one of $a + e^{i\pi/3}(b-a)$ or $a+e^{-i\pi/3}(b-a)$. Then expand everything into real and imaginary parts.

You can show your isosceles triangle equality $$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=(y-y_2)^2+(x-x_2)^2$$
leads to $$(2x-x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_1) = (2y-y_1-y_2)(y_1-y_2)$$
and so to $$\frac{x-\frac{x_1+x_2}2}{y_1-y_2} = \frac{y-\frac{y_1+y_2}2}{x_2-x_1}.$$
Call the value of this $k$, so $x=\frac{x_1+x_2}2 + k(y_1-y_2)$ and $y=\frac{y_1+y_2}2 + k(x_2-x_1)$,
and substitute these into your first equality on the sides and solve for $k$
to get $k=\pm\frac12$ for your right-angled isosceles triangle
(and similarly $k=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ for your equilateral triangle).

I'm trying to write the most simple way I know . You actually can get 2 isoceles right triangles if you're given only two points as vertices.
Let the other vertex have coords $C(h,k)$.
$A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$ are known. Let slope be indicated by $m$.
$$m(AC)=\frac{k-y_1}{h-x_1}$$
$$m(AB)=\frac{k-y_2}{h-x_2}$$
As $$BC \perp AC, m(AC)m(BC)=-1$$
Or $$\frac{(k-y_1)}{(h-x_1)}=\frac{-(h-x_2)}{(k-y_2)}$$
Squaring both sides:-
$$\frac{(k-y_1)^2}{(h-x_1)^2}=\frac{(h-x_2)^2}{(k-y_2)^2}...(i)$$
Again by using distance formula,
$$(h-x_1)^2+(k-y_1)^2=(h-x_2)^2+(k-y_2)^2$$
These two can be solved simultaneously to find out $x$ and $y$.
For Equilateral triangle:-
$$(h-x_1)^2+(k-y_1)^2=(h-x_2)^2+(k-y_2)^2(AC=BC)$$
$$(h-x_1)^2+(k-y_1)^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2(AC=AB)$$
$$(h-x_2)^2+(k-y_2)^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_2-y_2)^2(BC=AB)$$
Choosing any two of these equations, you can derive the formula by yourself as well, simultaneously.
